# McAfee virus in Microsoft Edge on Linux

Tags: virus, microsoft-edge, ubuntu-22.04

I've been getting popups like this on Ubuntu 22.04.  Apparently this is from the Microsoft Edge browser and it mentions McAfee though the Edge logo and mentioning McAfee may be disinformation.

How do I get rid of this?

[image: McAfee Microsoft Edge virus on Ubuntu 22]

Comment: Stop using MS Edge? There are many native Linux browsers, such as Firefox, Chrome, Brave, Tor, etc. Must you use Edge? Re: ww1-notifsmartads.azurewebsites.net, see https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/14884-azurewebsites-net-pop-up-scam.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik This is not an Edge only problem, the same may happen to users of other browsers supporting notifications, too.

Comment: I use Edge because it has cross platform bookmarking.  I used to use Brave, but it suddenly lost several weeks of my bookmarks.  Brave bookmarks are just not reliable.  I wish there was a cross-platform, cross-browser bookmark manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This popup seems to be a simple website notification through the browser.

You should be able to stop the website (`ww1-notifsmartads.azurewebsites.net`) from sending you those by remove the permission in the browser settings.

1. In **Microsoft Edge** press the meatball (three dot) menu icon and go to ***Settings***
2. Go to the **Cookies and site permissions** section
3. Scroll down and click on **Notifications**
4. Check the allowed section to see which websites are there, and locate `ww1-notifsmartads.azurewebsites.net`
5. Click the 3 dots on the site of this entry and press ***Remove***